# 2 servers, same website on both: IE shows two slightly different version

Tags: asp.net, html, iis, windows-server-2003, impromptu

I'm getting a weird issue involving IIS and IE, and I'll try to describe it clearly.

I have a regular html-css-js/jquery website that I've developed locally. Now that it's ready, I'm trying to deploy it on a server.

Once it's hosted on the server, I see two problems in IE only:

- The rendering is slightly different: there's a few pixels of additional white space all around my website (so the contents is actually more 'compressed' than when viewed locally).
- Some JS issues: I'm using the Impromptu jQuery popup plug-in, and the callback I specify in its 'loaded' event pre-populates its forms fields. In FF it works, but in IE the fields don't get populated until I close the popup and open it again. This worked locally on all browsers.
- As weird as it sounds, the text in my jQuery popup dialog does not seem to have the 'ClearType' technology applied. The text is like '1 pixel thin' and not anti-aliased like everywhere else.

I have uploaded my website to another server and it runs perfectly fine. The issue is that I need to put it on the first server and I don't know what's wrong. Both servers are on Win 2k3 with IIS 6, .NET 3.5.

Any pointers as to what is going wrong? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the IE developer toolbar to debug your css. Could also be a caching issue if it looks like an older version.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535

Comment: Quick way to rule this out is to do a Ctrl-F5 refresh instead of a F5 refresh (ignores client cache for the request).

Comment: This led me to find the problem, thanks. It turns out that once deployed, IE8 automatically goes in 'Compatibility View' and it breaks a couple of things in my layout. I'll now be looking at why it goes into this mode automatically and how I can prevent it.

Comment: The HTML5 doc type <!DOCTYPE html> will kick ie into standards mode. http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-doctype/

Comment: I also find this useful when debugging IE stuff.  http://www.blunck.info/iehttpheaders.html

Comment: Turns out IE has a default setting that turns on Compatibility View for intranet sites. I didn't mention this in my original question, but it's for an intranet. I "solved" this by adding X-UA-Compatible: IE=8 to headers sent by IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the "security zone" in the Internet Explorer status bar is the same when viewing the site between the 2 servers.